# Redirect requests inside html page to go through proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy

I have a proxy, and I've fetched contents of the webpage I need, like https://google.com. However, I need to be able to then also redirect all the other requests for resources to go through the proxy. So, all images and scripts go back through the proxy. Additionally, all links also go back through the proxy. How can I access all of the requests and do this? Would this be through modifying the HTML of the site? Now, I should be able to serve the contents of any dynamic or static site on a localhost, without having certain elements and scripts not loading.

Comment: Typically proxies are set up in the network configuration of the operating system. Modifying HTML (and also JS of course, because the sites may contain ajax requests) is a cumbersome task because links may come in various forms, you may not be able to detect just by parsing HTML or JS.

Comment: Can you explain what kind of proxy you are using? Generally, when people say "proxy" they mean a SOCKS or network proxy which forces traffic to pass through it. This doesn't appear to be what you mean, so please give more details about your proxy.

Comment: _What is your application?_ For scraping: It sounds like you're looking for [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer). See example: [examples/proxy.js](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/examples/proxy.js) as well as links and downstream scrapers. For desktop apps, frameworks like electron (["web embeds"](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/web-embeds)) or tauri should be able to serve webpages within the app.

Comment: @Codebling Im using a forward proxy. What I needed was all requests to change the url to go back to the proxy and fetch the contents. I think I've fixed that now, with my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution!

Using a service worker I can redirect requests to go back through the forward proxy. This example proxies requests from an old api version to a new one (this isn't what Im doing though. It would add a certain url, like `https://api.allorigins.win/get?url=` to the beginning):

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', e => {
  const {url} = e.request;
  if(url.includes('https://api.your.domain/api/v1/') {
    const newUrl = url.replace('/api/v1/', '/api/v2/');
    e.respondWith(fetch(newUrl));
  }
});
```

This article essentially fixes my problem: https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-run-a-proxy-server-inside-your-browser-8b96ea2ef1ea

Comment: The question specified that this is a node runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Your question states that you *have* a proxy, but your answer implies that you are *implementing* a proxy.

It sounds like you're asking for a Node.js solution, since question was tagged `node.js` and notice says

> The answer needs to detail how to implement this in NodeJS, and provide working code examples.

In Node.js, you can achieve this using [HTTP Party's `http-proxy` library](https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy)

Install it with `npm install http-proxy`.

Then match routes using your web framework, and rewrite the requests as needed.

In Express:

```
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
  autoRewrite: true,  //rewrites the location host/port
  changeOrigin: true, //change "Origin" header
}); 

app.use('/api/v1/',(req, res, next) => {
  //redirect requests from `https://api.your.domain/api/v1/` to `https://api.your.domain/api/v2/`
  //subpaths like /api/v1/me will also be changed (e.g. `/api/v2/me`)
  proxy.web(req, res, {target: 'https://api.your.domain/api/v2/'}, next );
});
```